# Uncaught TypeError when using loadGeoJSON

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

when I run the following javascript code:

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137.883}
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mycanvas'), mapOptions);
  map.data.loadGeoJSON("<?php echo site_url() ?>js/google.json");

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Any ideas why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: use `loadGeoJson` instead of 'loadGeoJSON'

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried your suggestion, and now I get this error:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ptax.ca/js/google.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://results.ptax.ca' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You are running your test in a different domain than ptax.ca (perhaps www.ptax.ca...)

Comment: You are right @geocodezip.  I was having a problem related to XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  I had to modify the permissions for cross domain scripting.  Thanks.